# serialize and deserialize self reference object in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a class A like this

```
class A
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public object[] Content { get; set; }
        public string[] jsonContent { get; set; }

        public A()
        {

        }

        public A(string type)
        {
            this.Type = type;
        }

        public A(string type, object[] content)
        {
            this.Type = type;
            this.Content = content;
        }

        public string ToJson()
        {
        int len = Content.Length;
        string[] jsonContentTmp = new string[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < Content.Length; ++i)
        {
            jsonContentTmp[i] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Content[i]);
        }
        jsonContent = jsonContentTmp;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        return json;
        }

        public static A ToA(string str)
        {
        Request a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(str);
        return a;
        }
    }
```

Consider bellow:

```
A sub1 = new A();
A sub2 = new A();
object[] obj = {sub1, sub2};
A test = new A("type", obj);
```

When I want to serialize `test`, I receive exception

> self reference

I tried `PreserveReferencesHandling` but i couldn't deserialize and receive exception

> 'cannot preserve reference toarray'

.
Any idea to serialize and deserialize it?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems this is done on purpose to prevent Stackoverflow exceptions. No pun intended. You have to turn PreserveReferences on, to enable self referencing:

[Serialising Circular references](http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/)

In your AppStart in Global.asax try the following:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
};

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonNetFormatter(jsonSerializerSettings));
```